# Hash value lengths

Tags: php, encryption

When referring to the length of a hash value such as sha1 or md5 in PHP, is it correct to interpret that as the size of the hash *in memory* rather than the number of characters present in the literal?

Comment: A literal is a value specified directly in the source code. So what exactly do you mean with "the number of characters present in the literal"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the minimum number of bits required to store the hash unambiguously.

```
>>> len(hashlib.md5('foo').digest()) * 8
128
>>> len(hashlib.sha1('foo').digest()) * 8
160
>>> len(hashlib.sha512('foo').digest()) * 8
512
```

Comment: Isn't `hashlib` a Python library? The native PHP seems to use the `md5` method, which outputs hexadecimals by default.

Comment: @owlstead: So what. The size of the hash will still be the same, even if the length of the representation differs.

Comment: @owlstead: You *do* know that hex digits only represent **4** bits per character... right?

Comment: @owlstead: Fun fact: *Hashes are language-independent.*

Comment: @owlstead: While nothing in your answer is grossly inaccurate (I'd say MD5 is not so much "broken" as just impossible to consider secure anymore), most of it is trivially derivable from the basic facts.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does. However, that size is tightly related to the amount of characters in the string -- if you get a raw string, you'll get 1 character per 8 bits; if you get hex digits (the default), you're getting 1 character per 4 bits.

Answer (score 0):

The principal output of a secure hash function is always defined in bits. So when referring to the output of a hash function a cryptographer always talks about e.g. 128 bits for the broken MD5 algorithm, 160 bits for SHA1 and obviously 256 bits for SHA-256.

Most crypto APIs however only work with bytes. This means that if there is a specific method present to indicate hash size, that more often than not the size in bytes is returned. So that would be 16, 20 and 32 bytes for the above algorithms.

Of course, the bytes are returned in e.g. hexadecimals then the length *in characters* of the string would be double that. The string length should then return 32, 40 or 64 characters. If that translates to an identical number of bytes depends on the character encoding (e.g. using UTF-16 would double the number of bytes).

Hash functions do have a big internal state, so the number of bytes taken by a running implementation is much higher than number of bits in the output. It is not that high that you would notice on a modern PC though.